# Python: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, module found

Tags: python, file-io, typeerror

I am new to Python, just learning.

I am taking one of the file as input and I want to print the text on the console using python.

```
# This will take the file as input

import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():

    print "The file name you provided is " + fileinput.filename()

    #file of = open(fileinput, "r", 0)
    with open(fileinput,'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read()
        print "This is your actual data \n\n" + data
```

The error I'm experiencing is:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, module found
```

Could any one please help me out on this please.

Comment: You don't need to open the file at all. Look at what the `fileinput` module actually does.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is in the line below:

```
with open(fileinput,'r') as myfile:
```

`fileinput` is a module. I presume you mean to have:

```
with open(fileinput.filename(),'r') as myfile:
```